# Im trying to change the title of my tk window but it doesn't change

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()

root['bg'] = 'dark blue'
root.title = ('Quiz')
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried to think of alot of solutions but they dont possibly work. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
root.title('Quiz')
```

instead of

```
root.title = ('Quiz')
```